# Documentation or Library to create server-side YQL

Tags: javascript, java, yql, yahoo-api

With the recent retirement of the [Yahoo Query Language API](https://developer.yahoo.com/yql/) , it would be nice to replace the server-side component with something of my own. I've searched and I could not find anything but YQL clients out there -- in fact, I had trouble even finding complete documentation about the Yahoo Query Language structure and syntax of what is typically returned.

Does anyone know of a server-side library that can do this (preferably Java, but I'll look at anything), or have some more complete documentation of the API?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question. I found some documentation on Yahoo's site. Note that I could not find this linked from the main YQL page (I had to use DuckDuckGo and Google to find it). In fact, there are few pages that I found that are removed; I suspect this documentation will be fully removed sometime soon.

- https://developer.yahoo.com/yql/guide/overview.html
- https://developer.yahoo.com/yql/guide/response.html
- https://developer.yahoo.com/yql/guide/select.html
- https://developer.yahoo.com/yql/guide/external_tables.html
- https://developer.yahoo.com/yql/guide/dev-external_tables.html
- https://developer.yahoo.com/yql/guide/users-overview.html
- https://developer.yahoo.com/yql/guide/yql_execute.html
- https://developer.yahoo.com/yql/guide/yql_storage.html
- (I don't have enough reputation to paste more than 8 links, so these are the other pages without the full path):
- iud.html
- yql-users-guide.html
- yql_code_tutorials.html

Though if someone has anything more complete or even some code that can act as a replacement for the YQL server, I'll switch your answer to be the correct one. Thanks!